# Type of enum values

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I can obtain a type representing the keys of an interface with:

```
interface I { a: string; b: string; }
const i: keyof I; // typeof i is "a" | "b"
```

Is there a way to similarly obtain a type representing the values of an enum?

```
enum E { A = "a", B = "b" }
const e: ?; // typeof e is "a" | "b"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of values of an enum can be infered as a type with some help of the [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) operator:

```js
enum E { A = "a", B = "b" }

type EValue = `${E}`
// => type EValue = "a" | "b"

const value: EValue = "a" // => ✅ Valid
const valid: EValue = "b" // => ✅ Valid
const valid: EValue = "" // =>  Invalid
```

Reference article: [Get the values of an enum dynamically](https://dev.to/prod/mastering-enums-in-typescript-1c1j#enum-get-values)
*(disclaimer: author here)*

Answer (score 1):

```
enum E { A = "a", B = "b" }
const e: keyof typeof E;
```

[Playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Name%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Fred%2C%20Vilma%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Names%20%3D%20keyof%20typeof%20Name%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20Names%20%3D%20%22Fred%22%20%7C%20%22Vilma%22%3B%0D%0Atype%20Data%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20data%3A%20%7B%5Bname%20in%20Names%5D%3A%20Data%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Fred%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Vilma%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getData(name%3A%20Names)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20data%5Bname%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%20in%20TS%202.6%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: Unfortunately, the type of `e` is `"A" | "B"` (the enum cases), not `"a" | "b"` (the enum values).

Comment: Oh, so just do `const e: E` no ? Edit: I see in this [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Name%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Fred%20%3D%20%22F%22%2C%20Vilma%20%3D%20%22V%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20Name%20%3D%20%22F%22%3B) that the autocompletion works but there is the "is not assignable" warning.

Comment: `E` is the enum type. I'm looking for the type of its values, which is a union of the string types `"a"` and `"b"` (`"a" | "b"`).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the name of the enum is, itself, an alias for the union of its values' types. The following code demonstrates:

```
enum WaterType {
    Lake  = 0,
    Ocean = 1,
    River = 2,
    Creek = 3,
};

let xxx: 0|1|2|3 = 2;
let yyy: WaterType = xxx; // OK
let zzz: 0|1|2|3 = yyy;   // OK
```

Enums are just a little confusing because the enum's name refers to the type (like `0|1|2|3`) in some contexts, but in other contexts it refers to an object by the same name. The `WaterType` object is similar to this object:

```
const WaterTypeObject = {
    Lake  : 0 as 0,
    Ocean : 1 as 1,
    River : 2 as 2,
    Creek : 3 as 3,
};
```

And `typeof WaterType` is virtually the same as `typeof WaterTypeObject`:

```
let aaa: typeof WaterType       = WaterType;
let bbb: typeof WaterTypeObject = aaa; // OK
let ccc: typeof WaterType       = bbb; // OK
```

In contexts where a type is expected, `WaterType` means `0|1|2|3`, but you can write `typeof WaterType` instead to get the type of the enum object:

```
// VS code reports: type WaterTypeString = "Lake" | "River" | "Ocean" | "Creek"
type WaterTypeString = keyof typeof WaterType;
// VS code reports:   type WaterTypeNumbers = WaterType
// which really means type WaterTypeNumbers = 0|1|2|3
type WaterTypeNumbers = (typeof WaterType)[WaterTypeString];
```

Just be sure not to write "keyof Enum", e.g. `keyof WaterType` is the same as `keyof number`, which is definitely not what you want.

Fun fact: `keyof typeof WaterType` is a lie. the keys of `WaterType` are actually `"Lake"|"River"|"Ocean"|"Creek"|0|1|2|3` (e.g. `WaterType["Creek"]==3` and `WaterType[3]=="Creek"`.)