# How to strongly type the "value" attribute to be str or a custom type?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, enums, python-typing, pylance

When using the Pylance (ms-python.vscode-pylance) VS Code extension in strict type checking mode, I get a type error on my custom Enum value for the following code:

```py
def println_ctrl_sequence(message: str, ctrlSequence: Union[ANSICtrlSequence, str]):
    """
    This function is use with  terminals to print the message
    with colors specified by a, ANSI control sequence that 
    can be either a str or a console.ANSICtrlSequence object.
    """
    if type(ctrlSequence) == ANSICtrlSequence:
        ctrlSequenceStr: str = ctrlSequence.value
    else:
        ctrlSequenceStr = ctrlSequence
    
    print("%s%s%s" % (
        ctrlSequenceStr,
        message,
        ANSICtrlSequence.RESET.value
    ))
```

The type error is detected on the `ctrlSequenceStr: str = ctrlSequence.value` line since `ctrlSequence.value`is detected as being of type `Any | Unknown`. So my objective is to strongly type the `value` attribute of my extended `Enum`:

```py
# python enum : https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html 
from enum import Enum

class ANSICtrlSequence(Enum):

    # basic control sequences
    RESET = "\033[m" 

    # full control sequences
    PASSED = "\033[1;4;38;5;76m" 
    FAILED = "\033[1;5;38;5;197m"
```

I have tried things like for instance doing `ANSICtrlSequence(str, Enum)` as specified [here in "String-based enum in Python" Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58608362/2745495) without success.

I have read the class `enum.pyi` and I can understand why the type of value is what it is:

```py
class Enum(metaclass=EnumMeta):
    name: str
    value: Any
    ...
```

I can't find a way to type my value attribute to be a str anywhere in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) or on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016066/type-of-enum-values). So is it possible? Is there a way **to override the type of an inherited attribute**? Or do I need to extend the Enum class with for instance an equivalent of the IntEnum that could be StrEnum for instance? Maybe I need to write my own strongly typed Enum class? Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem comes not *entirely* from `Enum.value` but from including `str` as a possible type of `ctrlSequence`. Pylance seems to check if all the types included in the `Union` has a `.value` attribute, and for `str`, of course, it doesn't have `.value` so Pylance doesn't know what type to expect (*that's* the "Unknown").

We can reproduce a *similar* "Unknown" error without using an `Enum`:

```
x = 5
print(x.value)
```

[image: similar error without enum]

In your case, following the [string-based enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608361/string-based-enum-in-python) solution and inheriting from `str` when defining your `Enum` is still necessary, as that indicates to type-checkers (here, Pylance) that your Enum `.value`'s are of `str`-type.

So, you definitely need this to strongly type your Enum:

```
class ANSICtrlSequence(str, Enum):
    RESET = "\033[m" 
    PASSED = "\033[1;4;38;5;76m" 
    FAILED = "\033[1;5;38;5;197m"
```

But then, it still shows up as

> Type of "value" is partially unknown
> ^ Type of "value" is "Any | Unknown*"

because in `Union[ANSICtrlSequence, str]`, the type of `.value` for `ANSICtrlSequence` is `Any` and the type of `.value` for `str` is Unknown. This issue with `str` is evident when you reverse the order of the Union to `Union[str, ANSICtrlSequence]`, which then becomes

> Type of "value" is "Unknown | Any"

...indicating the "Unknown" is tied to the `str`. Basically, my point is **you should not be focusing on typing the `.value` attribute of the Enum, because the problem is with including `str`**. The error actually disappears if you remove the `Union` and just use `ANSICtrlSequence`:

```
class ANSICtrlSequence(str, Enum):
    RESET = "\033[m" 
    PASSED = "\033[1;4;38;5;76m" 
    FAILED = "\033[1;5;38;5;197m" 

def println_ctrl_sequence(message: str, ctrlSequence: ANSICtrlSequence):
    # Pylance does not complain here
    ctrlSequenceStr: str = ctrlSequence.value
```

...which indicates there isn't any problem with your `Enum` in the first place.

But I understand why there's a Union in the code. Unfortunately, Pylance doesn't. It doesn't understand that by the time the code gets to `ctrlSequence.value` the code already checked that `ctrlSequence` is an `Enum`.

Interestingly, what does work is to change how to check for the type. Instead of [`type(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), use [`isinstance(obj, classinfo)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
class ANSICtrlSequence(str, Enum):
    RESET = "\033[m" 
    PASSED = "\033[1;4;38;5;76m" 
    FAILED = "\033[1;5;38;5;197m" 

def println_ctrl_sequence(message: str, ctrlSequence: Union[ANSICtrlSequence, str]):
    if isinstance(ctrlSequence, ANSICtrlSequence):
        ctrlSequenceStr: str = ctrlSequence.value
    else:
        ctrlSequenceStr = ctrlSequence
```

[image: no errors with isinstance]

...which satisfies Pylance and fixes the errors :)

I hope this isn't a case of "*it works on my environment*", but I almost always use `isinstance` instead of `type` when checking for an object's type, and I don't get any Pylance errors with Enums or Unions with Enums in my codes. I don't know how Pylance works but here's a related Q&A on the topic: [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/2745495)

If you *really* need to use `type(ctrlSequence)`, then you can use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast), which:

> Cast a value to a type.
>
> This returns the value unchanged. To the type checker this signals that the return value has the designated type, but at runtime we intentionally don’t check anything (we want this to be as fast as possible).

```
from typing import Union, cast

class ANSICtrlSequence(str, Enum):
    RESET = "\033[m" 
    PASSED = "\033[1;4;38;5;76m" 
    FAILED = "\033[1;5;38;5;197m" 

def println_ctrl_sequence(message: str, ctrlSequence: Union[ANSICtrlSequence, str]):
    if type(ctrlSequence) == ANSICtrlSequence:
        ctrlSequence = cast(ANSICtrlSequence, ctrlSequence)
        ctrlSequenceStr: str = ctrlSequence.value
    else:
        ctrlSequenceStr = ctrlSequence
```

[image: no errors by using cast]

...which again satisfies Pylance and fixes the errors :) The `cast` enforces the type-checker (here, Pylance) that `ctrlSequence` is your Enum type, and the `.value` is indeed a string.

Comment: Ok brilliant. The solution with `isinstance()` finally removed the "false" error detected by Pylance. Thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this question myself, and ended up finding a simple practical solution: just declare `value: <your_type_here>` in the enum body and forcibly ignore Pyright's warning that `"value" incorrectly overrides property of same name in class "Enum"` using an end-of-line comment.

For example, the following typechecks for me in the Pylance VSCode extension `v2023.9.30`:

```py
from enum import Enum


class ANSICtrlSequence(Enum):
    value: str # pyright: ignore[reportIncompatibleMethodOverride]

    # basic control sequences
    RESET = "\033[m" 

    # full control sequences
    PASSED = "\033[1;4;38;5;76m" 
    FAILED = "\033[1;5;38;5;197m" 


foo = ANSICtrlSequence(input())
print(foo.value.upper()) # type of `foo.value` is determined to be string (for intellisense, type checks, etc.)
```