# Infer the Values of a TypeScript Enum at the Type Level

Tags: typescript, enums, type-inference

I am trying to create a generic type called `EnumValues` that accepts an enum instance as a parameter and outputs the type for the values of the enum. The solution should be such that specific enum value strings are individually listed and not simply combined into a general string type.

For instance, given the following instance:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    First = "first-value",
    Second = "second-value",
    Third = "third-value"
}
```

The type should be as follows:

```js
type EnumValues<T> = ...;

type MyEnumValues = EnumValues<MyEnum>; //: "first-value" | "second-value" | "third-value";
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=59&pln=7&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKCpqAxAlgJwGcAXKAXigCIAzAkgWgDcBDAGzGEoBoMsBlYAGMA9iAAm5KoSGixTNh269MAFQAWBCRUrEN+OS3ac0AXzRpicAA7AoSSADUFwQgB4VAPknx7EANoA1sBwwtSwiMgAugDcUAD0cVBiwi4gAOSkAO7C+AHmljbhvk5GhJLFzm4+yB7K8YkAegD8QA)

The following attempts didn't work:

```js
MyEnum[keyof MyEnum];
MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum];
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I accidentally omitted the expected part. I have updated the question accordingly. The thing is that the enum is located in a third-party library so I don't have write access. I don't want to import the enum, I just want the values for auto-completion and type-safety. The reason behind that is that I simply don't like using enums due to inconsistency with bundlers' outputs.

Comment: I think you have to make it a const enum

Comment: I know I've seen a question on this...and that it's a lot harder than it sounds. Not having any luck finding it so far. :-|

Comment: [Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016066/type-of-enum-values). And it's not *hard* (anymore), it's just obscure: ```type EnumValues<T extends string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined> = `${T}`;``` [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpKKgN)

Comment: Since TS4.1 all you need to do is serialize your enum via template literal type, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAPPvN). See the linked q/a for more info

Comment: @DanielA.White - Turns out you don't (anymore?).